# Cross Sign an intermediate certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, ca, authority

I have 2 Root Certificates for internal use, that have been imported into the trust stores. I want to issue intermediate certificates and want them to be signed by both root certificates, so if one certificates is not trusted anymore the certificate itself is still trusted through the other CA.

I came to the point that I can sign the intermediate key by both CAs - which would give me 2 signed certificates with the same information.

I would like to know if/how I can connect both certificates so I have one certificate. As I understand, each certificates contains only 1 CA info, so if that CA gets distrusted, the certificate is not trusted too although signed by the remaining trusted CA.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [pki cross certification site:security.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=pki+cross+certification+site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com) and [How to properly create and use cross-signed CAs and certificates](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/133221/29925). There's a lot to a cross certified signer in various PKIs. Its too much to cover here at Stack Overflow.